# HTTP PUT Request in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have been able to deal with all other http methods except PUT method. I have an edit form with which I am able to fetch the already stored data back into the form but after I click the submit button to re-save the edited data, nothing happens. What could be the problem? Below is what i have done.

Edit game form

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm(e)" #e="ngForm" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="game_name">Name of Game</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="game_name" [(ngModel)]="eGame.game_name"  >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="game_type">Type of Game</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="game_type"  [(ngModel)]="eGame.game_type">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In my component

```
eGame = {
    game_name:"",  //set default values
    game_type:""
};

onSubmitForm(game){
    this.httpService.updateGame(game.id)
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data)
        )
}


gameEdit(game){ //function called to fetch data into edit form 

    this.eGame = game ;
    console.log(game)
}
```

Service for my games

```
updateGame(game){

    const body = JSON.stringify(game);
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.put('url' +game.id, body, headers)
        .map((data:Response) =>data.json())
}
```

Comment: variable name `e-game` would not work.. make `eGame`

Comment: @PankajParkar, it's still not working after correction. Although, i am able to fetch the already stored data back into the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's a simple mistake in your `template`. Do this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm(e)" #e="ngForm">

onSubmitForm(game) {
  this.httpService.updateGame(game.value.id) // Note that you must call '.value'
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log(data)
    )
}
```

Or you can just pass the value directly on your template, as below:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm(e.value)" #e="ngForm">
```

Demo: <kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9CmhzqjDO1esf4FWRzxa?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Do this: `console.log(game.value)`;

Comment: No the page is reloading with no error and nothing in the console